# Как искать в JSONB колонке при помощи Hibernate и criteriabuilder?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jsonb

Хочу сделать поиск, на уровне базы в JSONB колонке, как это реализовать при помощи Hibernate?
Данная колонка является списком

```
class A{
     @Type(type = "jsonb")
     @Column(name = "myItems", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "jsonb")
             private List<Item> items; 
    }

class Item{
    private String fieldA;
    private int fieldB;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для поиска вхождения одного json объекта в другой в postgresql есть оператор **@>** работает для любых json типов, которому соответствует функция jsonb_contains(jsonb, jsonb), но к сожалению она принимает в качестве аргументов тип jsonb. А hibernate передает параметр с типом character varying (возможно есть способы выполнить cast или указать тип). Чтобы обойти данный нюанс, я использовал собственную функцию jsonb_contains(jsonb, text), которая является обвязкой над стандартной с привидением типа, и в коде использую следующее выражение:

```
builder.isTrue(builder.function("jsonb_contains", Boolean.class,
               root.get(property), builder.literal(value));
```

Код функции jsonb_contains(jsonb, text):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.jsonb_contains(source jsonb, search text) 
RETURNS boolean AS 
'SELECT source @> search::jsonb' 
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Пример sql запросов для поиска вхождения:

```
SELECT '[{"name": "Bill", "age": 99}]'::jsonb @> '[{"age": 99}]' --return true
SELECT jsonb_contains('[{"name": "Bill", "age": 99}]'::jsonb, '[{"age": 99}]'::text) --return true

SELECT '[{"name": "Bill", "age": 99}]'::jsonb @> '[{"age": 9}]' --return false
SELECT jsonb_contains('[{"name": "Bill", "age": 99}]'::jsonb, '[{"age": 98}]'::text) --return false
```